# Lvalues and Rvalues in a multi-variable assignment

Tags: c, rvalue, lvalue

In the following:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 4;
```

How are the r-values and l-values classified? My guess is, from a parsing perspective, we would start off with R-to-L precedence on equals/assignment, so it would be:

```
c (lv) = 4 (rv)
```

Now `c` has the value `4` and `b` becomes the lvalue:

```
b (lv) = c/4 (rv)
```

And again:

```
a (lv) = b/4
```

So, perhaps it would look something like:

```
a (lv) = (
    b (lv) = (
        c (lv) = 4 (rv) // start here
    ) (rv)
) (rv)
```

Is that more-or-less a correct understanding of assignment, lvalues, and rvalues?

Comment: All of `a`, `b` and `c` are lvalues. But the result of the assignment `c = 4` is an rvalue. And the result of the assignment `b = (c = 4)` is an rvalue.

Comment: C does not use the term rvalue. there are lvalues and values of an expression that you get from for example lvalue conversion. But yes, your parse tree is otherwise right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, an lvalue is something that has a location, and that can therefore appear on the left-hand sign of an assignment operator.

In

```
a = b = c = 4;
```

I would say that `a`, `b`, and `c` are all lvalues, and that `4` is an rvalue.

If you need the value of something, and the something is an rvalue, you're done: you have a value.  If the something is an lvalue, you fetch a value from it, and that's the value you need.

If you're trying to store a value into something, and the something is an lvalue, you're in luck: you can store it.  But if the something is an rvalue, you can't, it's an error.

When you say

```
a = b = c = 4;
```

the first assignment that happens is indeed of `4` to `c`, and for this to work it's obviously important that `c` be an lvalue.  But when it comes time to do the second assignment, I don't think of that as reinterpreting `c` as an rvalue: the value to be stored in `b` is the same value that was just stored in `c`.  (Formally: "In `c = 4`, the resulting value is the value that was stored into `c`, and is an rvalue.")